# Cycles displacement mesh alignment

Tags: mesh, scene, displacement

I have an heightmap generated with world machine that I am using to displace a plane using the experimental features for micro displacement in 2.78c. Similar to that :
[image: http://www.kopilot.ch/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/blender-microdisplacement-adaptive-subsurf-material-panel.jpg]

I want to use a mesh representing the same terrain to be able to place additional objects on my scene without having to do it via the rendered view (since the displacement is not visible in the material view).

I figured I could do it with a mesh of the same heigthmap generated with world machine, but I have to eyeball it to align the two terrains since I'm not sure which values I have to put in the nodes of the displaced plane to get the exact same displacement.

Is there a way to have an accurate alignment of the mesh and the displaced plane without having to visually align the two objects ? Can I do it with a displace modifier with the same heightmap (how can I get the same displacement in the nodes and in the modifier) ?